# Rescaling and slowing down a movie at the same time with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, movie

I would like with ffmpeg to slow down a movie I am creating using the flag:

```
-filter:v "setpts=2.0*PTS"
```

However the height of my still images is not divisible by 2, so to avoid the error: `height not divisible by 2 (1238x833)`, I am using the flag:

```
-vf scale="trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2"
```

(I also tried `-vf scale=1238:-2`).

When I do this the film is generated but it isn't slowed down, like if the `-filter:v "setpts=2.0*PTS"` wasn't there.

Is there something particular to do in order to have both option working at the same time?

Here is the complete command I am using:

```
ffmpeg -an -i ./movie/cphmd1.%05d.ppm -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 5000k -r 24 -crf 18 -filter:v "setpts=2.0*PTS" -vf scale="trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -preset slow -f mp4 cphmd1_slower.mp4
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple filters acting on the same input, in series, have to be chained together. So,

```
ffmpeg -an -i ./movie/cphmd1.%05d.ppm -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 5000k -r 24 -crf 18 -vf "setpts=2.0*PTS,scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -preset slow -f mp4 cphmd1_slower.mp4
```